# Rails 3 omniauth-viadeo strategy gem causing Passenger LoadError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, passenger, omniauth, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm using Rails 3.2.2 and trying to set up the [viadeo strategy](https://github.com/Pasta/omniauth-viadeo) 0.0.5 for [omniauth](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth) 1.0-3.

**It actualy works fine in my developpment laptop with mongrel** (I'm able to authenticate myself with a viadeo account).

But, when I try to deploy my app in my production server using Apache/Passenger, I'm getting this Passenger error :

```
Could not find matching strategy for :viadeo. You may need to install an additional gem (such as omniauth-viadeo).
```

The fact is that i have correctly installed this gem using `gem install omniauth-viadeo`, then `bundle install`, and added the appropriate provider and keys in `initializers/omniauth.rb`.

**I'm already using facebook, twitter, linkedin, google and openid strategies which work fine** (either with mongrel or passenger).

Here is a part of my `Gemfile` related to omniauth :

```
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-oauth'
gem 'omniauth-oauth2'
gem 'omniauth-twitter'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'omniauth-linkedin'
gem 'omniauth-openid'
gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2'
gem 'omniauth-viadeo'
```

I've also tried to use the git repository like that `gem 'omniauth-viadeo', :git => 'https://github.com/pasta/omniauth-viadeo.git'` but this error appear when I run `bundle install` :

```
Git error: command `git clone 'https://github.com/pasta/omniauth-viadeo.git' "/home/myhome/.bundler/cache/git/omniauth-viadeo-a2d4364eb9f96f490d4d86c7a77260672f5c896f" --bare --no-hardlinks` in directory /home/myhome/dev/ruby/myapp has failed.
```

I'm wondering if I missed something or if there is an issue with this gem.

Comment: Same error here. Viadeo is working in development and not in staging/production. Also using facebook/twitter/openid/linkedin and all work well.
I'm posting an issue on github.

Comment: Github issue : https://github.com/Pasta/omniauth-viadeo/issues/1

Comment: Thanks for opening a github issue, i should have done that earlier since i'm always stuck.

Comment: Hey, are you using Devise-omniauth or omniauth only?

Comment: I'm using omniauth only.

Comment: Okay, on chooseyourboss.com we use devise-omniauth in production on heroku. I'll take a look tonight to create a simple application on heroku with omniauth only =)

Comment: Okay, I wrote the simplest app to reproduce your bug, but I couldnt. 
It's here : http://oviadeo-test.heroku.com/
the source is here : https://github.com/Pasta/oviadeo-test

At which moment of the deployment do you have this error?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not working to that project anymore (project has been shutdown). As I'm not able to push in production anymore, I can't reproduce this error. You can consider this issue closed. Thanks for your time, I'll let you know if I encounter any issues in the future.